# returnedObject property

Tags: apache-flex

I'm programming in Flex Builder Burrito for an mobile application.
I'm trying to get a variable from navigator.PopView()
and i found the following site: [adobe View and ViewNavigator](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/View+and+ViewNavigator)

On that page is written that you can get to an returnedObject:

> The ViewNavigator will save this object internally, and the new view can access it from with the navigator.returnedObject property.

The problem is when I want to acces the returnedObject flash builder doesn't seem to find that even the package isn't found.

Comment: How are you trying to access the returnedObject?  Show your code.  What version of Flash Builder/Flex are you using?  ( The Max preview release available on Adobe Labs? Or a release you got from a private pre-release program? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my problem on an other [site](http://remotesynthesis.com/post.cfm/passing-data-on-pop-methods-in-mobile-flex).

There it's plain simple explained.

Do the override public function createReturnObject():Object.

On the page where it needs to be send back.
Then on the popped view, you can acces it by returnedObject.

Answer (score 0):

On same page next lines are

> The property is a ViewReturnObject
>   which contains the object that was
>   returned 
>       and the context in which the removed view was pushed (See Setting
>   the View Context). 
>       ViewNavigator.poppedViewReturnedObject
>   is guaranteed to be set by the time
>   the new view 
>       receives the add event and will be destroyed after the view receives its
>   viewActivate 
>       event.

and also a NOTE

> Note, the return object is only stored when a view is popped of
>   the navigation stack
>        or replaced through the use of the pop and replace navigation
>   operations (e.g., 
>       replaceView, popView, etc...). It will be cleared after the new view
>   receives its 
>       ViewNavigatorEvent.VIEW_ACTIVATE event.

I think should try function to get popuped view **poppedViewReturnedObject** of **ViewNavigator** 
*Its description is also on same page*

```
public function get poppedViewReturnedObject():ViewReturnObject
```

Hopes that help

Comment: I know, 
but as Thibault also mentioned. 

It doesn't seem to find the returnObject in that class.

Comment: Are you using method "poppedViewReturnedObject" to get returnedObject?

Comment: Are you using SDK hero? you may try this lib https://github.com/pwalczyszyn/as3viewnavigator#readme

Comment: As I've now seen it's because i used the sdk Hero 4.5 indeed and the site was for the new flex sdk 4.5.0.20967. There it's like it's mentioned on the adobe site.